# JavaScript Library for Posing/Rigging Figures

Tags: javascript, html, animation, game-physics

Can anyone recommend a JavaScript+HTML5 library that supports "posable figures"?   Think about those wooden dolls that artists use to practice drawing, I would like functionality something like that for the browser.  Essentially, the user should be able to pose a virtual doll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Box2DJS](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/). It's a JavaScript port of the popular Box2d physics engine.

Comment: you wouldn't of a 3d library would you?  it would be nice to have a figure that could also be rotated

Comment: Would recommend https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js . Doesn't have physics though.